# convert: Postscript delegate failed - converting text PDFs

Tags: pdf, text, imagemagick, ghostscript

This one has me stumped.

I need to convert PDFs into jpgs.  I do so using the following commands :

```
$cmd = "convert ".$upload->pdf_name." -geometry 80x80 -density 80x80 -quality 100 ".$upload->thumb_name." 2>&1";
exec($cmd,$results);

$cmd_gif = "convert ".$upload->pdf_name." -geometry 640x640 -density 640x640 -quality 100 ".$upload->gif_name." 2>&1";
exec($cmd_gif,$results);
```

If I upload a PDF which is mostly image then I have no problems.  I get the thumbnail and preview.
If I upload a PDF which is mostly text, and print_r $results I get :

```
Array([0] => convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-wSgqd1Vp-00000001' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532. 
[1] => convert: Postscript delegate failed `/var/www/vhosts/site/uploadedfiles/tmp/2_77.pdf': @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/664. 
[2] => convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-8foOHRJR' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532. 
[3] => convert: missing an image filename `/var/www/vhosts/site/uploadedfiles/tmp/2_77_thumb.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3015. 
[4] => convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-M-zHuvtS-00000001' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532. 
[5] => convert: Postscript delegate failed `/var/www/vhosts/site/uploadedfiles/tmp/2_77.pdf': @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/664. 
[6] => convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-rJ8G814k' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532. 
[7] => convert: missing an image filename `/var/www/vhosts/site/uploadedfiles/tmp/2_77.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3015. )
```

I have Ghostscript 8.70 installed and imagemagick 6.7.1-0
My linux distro is CentOS release 5.6

Comment: Try using Ghostscript directly instead of imagemagick. That way at least you'll get an error message from Ghostscript if there's a problem. At least try "gs /var/www/vhosts/site/uploadedfiles/tmp/2_77.pdf" and report the result. BTW 8.71 is a little old now, the current version is 9.02 and we will be releasing 9.03 in a few weeks.

Comment: I updated to 9.02 and ran the command and got this :

`code` gs /var/www/vhosts/site/uploadedfiles/tmp/2_77.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.02 (2011-03-30)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 77 284
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 76.535998 283.463991
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<`code`

When I hit return it goes to <GS> and I have to quit to get back to bash

Comment: So that's a complete success, the GS> prompt is the intereactive PostScript interpreter. You can use -dBATCH and -dNOPAUSE to get around this and the pause between pages. So whatever the problem is, its specific to the invocation by ImageMagick. I'm afraid I can't help you with that, but if you can find out the command line its using, and if it still fails, then I would suggest opening a bug in the Ghostscript Bugzilla tracker at http://bugs.ghostscript.com, attaching the failing PDF file and giving the offending command line.

Comment: @Roger990: In which programming language are you trying to achieve this? -- Can you test with a direct `convert` commandline, adding a `-verbose` switch to it? This will show you the exact Ghostscript command ImageMagick is applying. Also, listen to what KenS advices you; he's one of the Ghostscript developers...

Comment: @pipitas: I'm programming in PHP.  When I run the command in putty I get the same error messages as displayed above.  This is only on pdfs that contain a high amount of text.  Graphical PDFs converte magically.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd command, `$cmd_gif`, asks ImageMagick to create a picture of dimensions (*"geometry"*) 640x640 pixels, while at the same time asking for a resolution (*"density"*) of 640x640...